# addition of two ruby floats gives unexpected result

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.0

When I add two floats in an irb console, the result is not as expected

```
10.43 + 4.56 # should be 14.99
```

But the actual result is

```
irb(main):001:0> 10.43+4.56
=> 14.989999999999998
```

What causes this?

Comment: asked a Bazillion times before!  Search for floating point precision and/or representation

Comment: @MitchWheat could you please post a link?

Comment: No, how about you try searching and you post a link! It's not difficult!

Comment: Interesting. I ran this on `irb` version 0.9.5 and it gave me 14.99, but on `irb` version 0.9.6 it gave me 14.989999999999998. I was going to say that conversion of decimal to binary and back again certainly could introduce a teeny bit of error, but I was a little surprised that these two versions behaved differently.

Comment: This may help: [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

Comment: @MitchWheat pretty unclear why being so rude. Googling it did not show up the result and I went until starting to write another SO question to get a link to this one. And the duplicate is apparently not the most obvious either, with 0 upvote at that time. Finally, I think we can agree on the fact that linking the web together with usefull content **IS** what makes its whole value. Well, I would definitely downvote your comment if I could!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior.  Floats are not guaranteed precision because, in short, computers are binary systems (as of 2013) and cannot correctly represent fractional values.  This is why you get "unexpected" results, when in reality this is how it will work until there is a non-binary machine that can correctly represent fractional values.

Comment: @MitchWheat TIL that binary systems can correctly represent fractions.  Unless of course you mean two longs one before the decimal point and one after.  Time to go do some research it seems.